# Jquery - scroll to top on parent page of iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to scroll the page which contains an iframe.
I want my parent page scroll to top when iframe loads the page which contains the Jquery code.

Here is the code that i am using right now, but it's not working:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
     window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');

}
</script>
</head>
```

Where is my mistake? Why when iframe page loads this page the parent one is not going to top?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can define function in parent page and call from iframe:
**for example:**
*parent:*

```
function top(){
    alert('scroll to top')
}
```

*iframe:*

```
<button onclick="parent.top()">top</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the parent page within an iframe that way.

If you have access to your parent page, try checking if the iframe it includes

```
$('#iframeID').load(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); // You have to point the animation to your <html> element if you want to scroll your page
});
```

Comment: No i can not do that.

Comment: try $(parent.document).ready(function(){
   $(parent.document.firstElementChild).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
  })